# Core Data Navigation with Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

My Core Data model looks like this:

[alt text http://fwdr.org/lg4q](http://fwdr.org/lg4q)

The `players` relationship of the entity `Game` is a **to many relationship** and will hold all the `player` objects related to that `Game` entity.

I have a `UITableView` that looks like [this](http://fwdr.org/wc1r) *<-- link* .
The Table View displays all the games, how would I, **when selecting a Game show/push another UITableView to display all the players in the `players` relationship.**

I have already attempted this but to no avail, I think I was on the right track but was plagued by to many errors which I was unable to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create another `UITableViewController` subclass, wrap it into navigation controller and push. Make sure to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your table views. You should pass Game object to second table view controller in order to build predicate for it.

Some code snippets:

Wrapping view controller into navigation in table view controller's `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
    TagsViewController *tagsViewController = [[TagsViewController alloc] initWithMode:TagsViewControllerModeSelect]; // You can view plain style, I've just created my initializer
    tagsViewController.unit = self.unit; // You can pass the Game here
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tagsViewController animated:YES];
    [tagsViewController release];
```

Here is fetched results controller lazy initializer

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(fetchedResultsController != nil)
        return fetchedResultsController;

    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StudyUnit" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSString *predicateString = [[DefaultsManager sharedInstance] filterMode] == kFilterModeShowAll ? @"explanation != '' AND show == YES" : @"ANY tag.show == YES AND explanation != '' AND show == YES"; 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString]; // Here goes your predicate to query players for particular game
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor* sortByWordDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"subject" ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortByWordDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

    NSFetchedResultsController* controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Hmm"];
    controller.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = controller;

    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortByWordDescriptor release];
    [sortArray release];
    [controller release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Then just implement `NSFetchedResultsController` delegates, send `performFetch` message and voila!

UPD:

Assuming your game object is generally `NSManagedObject` declared in the second controller:

```
NSManagedObject *game;
```

Then you can build predicate something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
//...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"game == %@", self.game];
```

This is just theoretically, can't test it sorry ^^

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going. I understand the first snippet but with the second snippet with `predicateString ` and `predicate` how do I query for those particular players? Other than that I understand exactly what you are doing, thanks very much!

Comment: Cheers, almost all done. ;)
Just unsure what to do with this code, `tagsViewController.unit = self.unit;` I've changed it to `playerViewController.game = self.unit;` but I am unsure what to replace `self.unit` with.

Comment: @Joshua: Assuming you have(gonna have) the same mechanism for the Game controller and you are using `NSManagedObject` for entity, then in `didSelectRowAtIndex` you can retrieve selected game object by `playerViewController.game = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 2):

In the second tableView since you already have the game object, you really do not need another `NSFetchedResultsController`.  You can get the players directly from the game object that gets injected into the second view controller and using the relationship display the players.

A second `NSFetchedResultsController` would only be necessary in this situation if you expected the players to change while the user is viewing that second controller.  Otherwise just walking the relationship is sufficient and will use less memory/cpu.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I will need the `NSFetchedResultsController` as I will be adding players within the second controller. Thanks anyway

Comment: You still would not need one because **YOU** (as in the view you are in) are adding them.  A `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed to notify **YOU** that something other than **YOU** has changed the data **YOU** are looking at.

Comment: Please see my further question on this about accessing `NSManagedObject`'s in a relationship without a `NSFetchedResultsController`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457876/getting-nsmanangedobject-from-a-relationship-without-nsfetchedresultscontroller